# Simple script for displaying before date

Tags: php, mysql

Apparently not so simple for me. I have a SELECT script that is calling for a list of assignments to display. That all works fine, but I just need something to tell the script that once it passes the due date (which is defined in the database as `duedate`). Any help would be great.

So for instance if today is December 3rd, and there's an assignment due on December 2nd. Because today is after December 2nd, that assignment won't show.

Here's the original MySQL script.

```
<?php 
session_start();
include("db.php");

$query  = "SELECT * FROM scuela_assignments WHERE 
assignments_teacher='".$_SESSION['username']."' 
ORDER BY assignments_duedate ASC LIMIT 0,      3; ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $name=$row['assignments_name'];
    $due=$row['assignments_duedate'];
    $class=$row['assignments_class'];
    echo "<div class='span2'><b>";
    echo $name;
    echo "</b><h6>";
    echo "</h6></br>";
    echo "<blockquote>";
    echo $due;
    echo "</blockquote>";
    echo"<a href='class.html?id=";
    echo $row['assignments_classid'];
    echo "'>";
    echo $class;
    echo "</a></div>";
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: I don't get you. Can you be more specific on what you mean of "tell the script that once it passes the due date"?

Comment: So for instance if today is December 3rd, and there's an assignment due on December 2nd. Because today is after December 2nd, that assignment won't show.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the database server time is set properly (so the mysql function `CURDATE()` returns the correct, expected date). You might want to try add something like this:

`SELECT *, IF(assignments_duedate < CURDATE(), 1, 0) AS assignment_duedate_passed FROM scuela_assignments`

so you could then check the value in the variable `$row['assignments_duedate_passed']`, for example:

```
if($row['assignments_duedate_passed']) {
  // due date has passed, do something
} else {
  // nope, do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you mean by

> I just need something to tell the script that once it passes the due
>   date

If you want to compare the field `duedate` you can insert that in the WHERE clause.

NOTE: There are two fields in your post `duedate` and `assignments_duedate`. If they are same you can replace `duedate` with `assignments_duedate`.

Eg.

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM scuela_assignments WHERE 
assignments_teacher='".$_SESSION['username']."' AND duedate < NOW()  
ORDER BY assignments_duedate ASC LIMIT 0,      3; ";
```

or

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM scuela_assignments WHERE 
assignments_teacher='".$_SESSION['username']."' AND duedate < _A_CALCULATED_VALUE_  
ORDER BY assignments_duedate ASC LIMIT 0,      3; ";
```

Here `NOW()` is a mysql function and `_A_CALCULATED_VALUE_` can be substitute to have any calculated value. If the `duedate` has no time part (assignments to be expired on) then you can use `CURDATE()`.